# New hangout indicator meanings

Tags: sms, google-hangouts

I have started using hangouts now that it has merged in with all my sms messages and it's cool.

However i was wondering if someone could explain the indicators that show up at the bottom left of the screen to me?

I currently know:

- TinyPortrait(transparent) = current point user has read to
- Dots (...) = user is typing

Unknown

- TinyPortriat(Solid) = i thought this might mean they are up to date,
  but considered it could be that they are watching the screen?
- Small Phone Icon = No idea what this means.

Are there any others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyPortriat(Solid): The user is reading the conversation.

Small Phone Icon: This indicates that the user is using the hangouts app on a mobile device.

TinyPotrait (Faded): The user read your messages above the icon.

Comment: Interesting, why does this seem to be intermittent, does it mean they have the app open at that point?

Comment: They have the app open and are looking at your messages

Answer (score 3):

There also seems to be a little green phone handset (unlike the white full phone mentioned in my question), indicating they are in a call.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solid green means you are using Hangouts and the person is online.

The SMS indicator means you are texting instead of using Hangouts.

Answer (score -1):

The green phone icon means the user is in a call with someone else. It goes away once they hang up

Comment: This answer has been mentioned on [existing answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/68530/44325) without adding substantial new information. Please prevent posting a duplicate answer.